# undefined method `have' for #<Object:0x007f997fabf778> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, cucumber, capybara

I am getting a undefined method error message for the 'have' method.

`expect(@gymhomepage.find_your_local_gym).to 
 have(@gymhomepage.find_your_local_gym.first_gym_location)`

I am trying to assert if first_gym_location css is located within the find_your_local_gym section.

[Please see my framework on Github](https://github.com/shafiqahmedmalik2010/we_are_friday)

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: No one is going to go read through your whole project on Github, your question needs to be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara doesn't provide a `have` matcher, it provides a bunch of `have_<something>` matchers.  Assuming `@gymhomepage.find_your_local_gym.first_gym_location` returns a CSS selector then you would use

```
expect(@gymhomepage.find_your_local_gym).to have_css(@gymhomepage.find_your_local_gym.first_gym_location)
```

If instead `@gymhomepage.find_your_local_gym.first_gym_location` is a method that finds the element already scoped you just need to do

```
expect(@gymhomepage.find_your_local_gym.first_gym_location).to be
```

since it would already be guaranteed to be scoped into the `find_your_local_gym` element by calling it on it (Assuming you haven't fallen into the XPath trap - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap)